# Read datetime value from CSV file into teradate

Tags: datetime, casting, teradata, sql-convert

I fairly new to teradata. I'm trying to read a csv file which has create_date column as datetime, trying to import the file into teradata temp table but unable to succeed. Please help me to resolve the issue. I have attached the sample script i have developed which working fine with date value

```
HandleTmpTable()
{
    bteq <<ENDSQL
        .LOGON $TARGET_DB/$TUSER,$TPWD; 
/* Drop the temporary tables */
        DROP TABLE ${TTMPDB}.test;

/* Create the temporary table test */
        CREATE TABLE ${TTMPDB}.test,
            NO FALLBACK,
            NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
            NO AFTER JOURNAL
        (
        NUMBER  VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
        NAME            CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
        PROGRAM             VARCHAR(20),
        CODE            CHAR(4),
        C_NAME          VARCHAR(255),
        CO_NAME     VARCHAR(50),
        CREATE_DATE         date format 'YYYY/MM/DD',
        UPDATE_DATE         date format 'YYYY/MM/DD',
        EXCLUDE_IND         CHAR(1) ,
        NUMBER          VARCHAR(40),
        FLAG            SMALLINT,
        NG_FLAG     SMALLINT    
        );
        .IF ERRORCODE <> 0 THEN .EXIT ERRORCODE;
        .QUIT 0;       
ENDSQL
    if [ $? -ne 0 ] 
    then
        Error "Unable to create the temporary table"
    fi

    Log "Temporary tables created successfully"
}
ImportFiles()
{

   bteq <<ENDSQL
        LOGON $TARGET_DB/$TUSER,$TPWD;
    DROP TABLE ${TTMPDB}.test_err1;
        DROP TABLE ${TTMPDB}.test_err2;
ENDSQL
   fastload <<ENDSQL
        .SESSIONS ${TFLSESS};
        .ERRLIMIT 1;
        .LOGON $TARGET_DB/$TUSER,$TPWD;
        SET RECORD VARTEXT ",";
        DEFINE
        file_NUMBER      (VARCHAR(35)),
                file_NAME                 (VARCHAR(4)),
                file_PROGRAM                         (VARCHAR(20)),
                file_CODE                    (VARCHAR(4)),
                file_C_NAME                    (VARCHAR(255)),
                file_CO_NAME         (VARCHAR(50)),
                file_CREATE_DATE                     (VARCHAR(10)),
                file_UPDATE_DATE                     (VARCHAR(10)),
                file_EXCLUDE_IND                     (VARCHAR(1)),
                file_NUMBER                   (VARCHAR(40)),
                file_FLAG                  (VARCHAR(6)),
                file_NG_FLAG         (VARCHAR(6))

        FILE=test.csv;

        SHOW;

    BEGIN LOADING ${TTMPDB}.test
    ERRORFILES ${TTMPDB}.test_err1, ${TTMPDB}.test_err2
    CHECKPOINT 25000000;
    INSERT INTO ${TTMPDB}.test
        (
        :file_NUMBER,
        :file_NAME,
        :file_PROGRAM,
        :file_CODE,
        :file_C_NAME,
        :file_CO_NAME,
        :file_CREATE_DATE ,
        :file_UPDATE_DATE ,
        :file_EXCLUDE_IND,
        :file_NUMBER,
        :file_FLAG,
        :fileNG_FLAG

          );

    END LOADING;    

ENDSQL
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]
    then
        Error "Unable to Load the temporary table"
    else
    rm -f test.csv
    fi

    Log "Temporary tables loaded successfully"
}
```

sample data:

```
FC-A,FC,Fraud,AA,AAAA,,17JAN2019:00:00:00,17JAN2019:00:00:00,N,,,
FC-B,FC,Fraud,BB,BBBBB,,17JAN2019:00:00:00,17JAN2019:00:00:00,N,,,
FC-C,FC,Fraud,CC,CCCCC,,17JAN2019:00:00:00,17JAN2019:00:00:00,N,,,
FC-D,FC,Fraud,DD,DDDDD,,17JAN2019:00:00:00,17JAN2019:00:00:00,N,,,
FC-E,FC,Fraud,EE,EEEEE,,17JAN2019:00:00:00,17JAN2019:00:00:00,N,,,
FC-F,FC,Fraud,FF,FFFFF,,17JAN2019:00:00:00,17JAN2019:00:00:00,N,,,
```

Let me know how read adn write the datetime value for create_date and update_date column from csv to teradate table

Comment: What is the exact error message?  `NUMBER` is a data type, so that may be a reserved keyword.  You also have the `NUMBER` column defined twice in your `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the same script, below things should change for the datetime:
(1) The column type should be timestamp. Timestamp(0) would do base from the sample data.
(2) In the fastload DEFINE, the field should have a length of 18.
(3) In the fastload insert, you can use below code:

```
:file_CREATE_TS(format 'DDMMMYYYY:HH:MI:SS')
```

Comment: Format would be 'ddmmmyyyy:hh:mi:ss' to load to TIMESTAMP. FastLoad only supports one data type conversion per field and no functions, so you can't put this in a DATE column in one step. With other utilities (e.g. MultiLoad) you could explicitly CAST to TIMESTAMP and then DATE, or SUBSTRING before converting to date, within the INSERT.

Comment: There's no `MON`, it's `MMM`: `FORMAT 'DDMMMYYYY:HH:MI:SS'`

Comment: Thanks for pointing dnoeth. The double asterisk was for the formatting here at stackoverflow. Just find it weird to have a ':' between the date and time element of the timestamp.